# How to run java class in Eclipse Che

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-che

I have just started using Eclipse che and started up a project. I have no Main class and I want to start running the project from a class called TBB_SQLBuilder.java within a package called Console.

I simply cannot figure out how to run it. I have a screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: and how is that supposed to work without a main class / main method?

Comment: Helpful comments please. You don't actually need a Main class to run a project in eclipse. So please provide helpful answers

Comment: You need something with a `public static void main(String[] args) ` method.  Do you have that?

Comment: I have a main method in the class

Comment: Right-click on that class and run it?

Comment: See the answer I have posted below. Che is not as intuitive as you may think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it isnt as straight forward as desktop Eclipse.

1. Create a bin folder
2. Go to the command tab on the left hand side of the IDS (I didn't have Run>Edit Commands tab for reasons I'm yet to understand)
3. Add a new command

I had to add

```
cd ${current.project.path}
javac -classpath ${project.java.classpath} -sourcepath ${project.java.sourcepath} -d ${project.java.output.dir} src/Console/TBB_SQLBuilder.java
java -classpath ${project.java.classpath}${project.java.output.dir} TBB_SQLBuilder
```

to get it to run.

I note the question has been downvoted. I suppose some thought this might be straightforwrd but it is worth noting that this is very different to the desktop IDE which provides a UI to create the run configuration. Che seems to rely on creating commands from a command line box in the command interface.